# Dictionary for multi-word term like low fat milk?

Tags: nlp

I am not a fluent English speaker, so maybe this question is trivial for native English speakers.

I am implementing a natural language processing system. I need to extract terms which have meanings by combining with several another words.

For example, I am supposed to extract ["I", "am", "drinking", "low fat", "low fat milk"] from "I am drinking low fat milk". Is it possible?

Comment: You can use collocation measures to extract such bigrams. Not sure how it works for trigrams.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you need by extracting **syntactic dependencies** between words. For instance, here, both "low" and "fat" are adjective modifiers of the noun "milk". Once these dependencies are found, then you can focus on the ones you need.

To find out these dependencies, you can use [Stanford dependency parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml), which is available in Java, Python, and PHP. You can experiment with the online version of the parser [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process).

Finally, this [paper](https://nlp.stanford.edu/~sebschu/pubs/schuster-manning-lrec2016.pdf) gives you a detailed understanding of the parser and the meaning of the tags.

Example:

For the sentence above, you will get the following relationships from the parser, where "amod" means adjective modifier:

`root ( ROOT-0 , drinking-3 )
nsubj ( drinking-3 , I-1 )
aux ( drinking-3 , am-2 )
amod ( milk-6 , low-4 )
amod ( milk-6 , fat-5 )
dobj ( drinking-3 , milk-6 )`

Comment: Can this method distinguish "low fat milk" or "cell phone" from "very beautiful view"?

Comment: Yes. It would. Because "very" will be an adverbial modifier to "beautiful" here. 

`root ( ROOT-0 , see-2 )
nsubj ( see-2 , I-1 )
det ( view-6 , a-3 )
advmod ( beautiful-5 , very-4 )
amod ( view-6 , beautiful-5 )
dobj ( see-2 , view-6 )`